# Integrity Constraints for date (using oracle) Current Date not working as it come up with error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_chk_future
  BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.date_time < sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'date_time must be in the future' );
  END IF;
END;
```

However the current date comes up as an error when entered such as 12/12/2021 (today date) but 13/12/21 and any date after the today date works.

Any ideas what's wrong.

Comment: you just missed to add an equality sign such as `:new.date_time <= sysdate` depending on the current logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* inserted values you wrote in the question, who-knows-what you really inserted. Because, those are **strings**, not date values. Therefore, Oracle tried to convert them to valid `DATE` datatype values and - according to what you said - failed.

It means that you should actually insert `DATE` values, like the following example shows (trigger is exactly the same as you made it):

```
SQL> create table your_table (date_time date);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_chk_future
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF( :new.date_time < sysdate )
  6    THEN
  7      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'date_time must be in the future' );
  8    END IF;
  9  END;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: truncated sysdate is set to midnight (which was in the past, and thus rejected):

```
SQL> insert into your_table values (trunc(sysdate));
insert into your_table values (trunc(sysdate))
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: date_time must be in the future
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_CHK_FUTURE", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_CHK_FUTURE'
```

May this year, also in the past:

```
SQL> insert into your_table values (date '2021-05-25');
insert into your_table values (date '2021-05-25')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: date_time must be in the future
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_CHK_FUTURE", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_CHK_FUTURE'
```

This *is* in the future, so it is accepted:

```
SQL> insert into your_table values (date '2021-12-26');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

As of

> the current date comes up as an error when entered such as 12/12/2021 (today date)

*Maybe* you meant to say

```
IF( :new.date_time < trunc(sysdate))
```

which truncates `sysdate` to midnight today. In that case, today's date is also accepted:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_chk_future
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF( :new.date_time < trunc(sysdate))
  6    THEN
  7      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'date_time must be in the future' );
  8    END IF;
  9  END;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into your_table values (date '2021-12-12');

1 row created.

SQL>
```